# Online circuit simulator

Tags: simulation

Are there sites to build circuits online using equipment such as Fluke 45 Digital Multimeter,  GW-Instek GFG-8216A function generator, Agilent E3620A power supply and Tektronix TDS1002B oscilloscope rather than a breadboard? This would be a useful tool to prepare for circuit labs using similar equipment.

Comment: No, those are too specific. The abstract features of the different equipment can be simulated to the extent you are able to model it, but not the full exact equipment part numbers. Also, I wouldn't call what you are building a "circuit," perhaps a "virtual lab" or "simulated bench" or something...

Comment: Get a simulator.

Comment: I've never tried it - how well does the schematic capture/circuit simulator that is linked in the Answer box do?

Comment: @CrossRoads:  If you can accurately represent your circuit with the parts it has available, it works OK.  It just doesn't have a whole lot of parts predefined (though you can tweak some of the models.)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: *without looking*, I don’t know of such a toolset, let alone something so brand-specific, to make a virtual lab for electronics. Seems like a worthwhile idea though for cash-strapped classrooms.

Having taken a look, I see that there are efforts to make ‘virtual labs’ that have notions of physical meters, signal generators and such. Below, a small sampling.

A basic one... https://dcaclab.com/en

A bit fancier: https://electricvlab.com/

And a snazzy 3D virtual sim from U of Madrid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZ5JTzch2cY

That said, you can go a long way with free tools like [LTSpice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) and [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) (linked right here on SE - the circuit icon in the edit window) to master the ideas of electronics and electricity. While they don’t emulate exactly your target equipment, they do have signal generators, probes, and waveform displays.

As a skill, being able to use Spice effectively (the engine powering these simulators) is far more powerful than using a TDS1002.